# What is a good way of rendering react-native components frequently?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm trying to build a simple TextView Component with react-native that displays the current value of a counter.

```
render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <BoldText style={styles.counterText}>
                Counter: {this.props.counter}
            </BoldText>
        </View>
    );
}
```

The counter is incremented every 10 ms and the TextView is re-rendered properly.

```
_startTimer() {
    let timer = require('react-native-timer');
    const interval = 10;
    timer.setInterval("counter interval", () => {
        this.props.incrementCounter(6);
    }, interval);
}
```

In order to update the props I used redux.

The only problem is that this task seems to be very cpu intensive as my iPhone temperature rises quiet fast. Is there a less cpu intensive way of rendering a Component at high frequency?

Comment: 10 ms is really really short time to update a component .. so you really need to update things every 10 ms ??? 60 frames per second ie around 16ms time to update things in rn.. 10ms is really short Refer: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance